# Mockito matchers InvalidUseOfMatchersException returning null

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito

I need to return null from:

```
Cookie controlCookieValue = getCookie(cookiesConfigBean.getControlCookieName());
```

I'm doing:

```
when(baseHandler.getCookie(any(String.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

but the code throws `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`. I tried using `anyObject()` and `anyString()`, but nothing works. The `baseHandler` object is a mock.

Comment: So your `getCookie()` method calls `baseHandler` inside

Comment: Please post the lines of setup just before your `getCookie` stub, and consider using a call to [`Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage()) immediately before your mock. Please also paste your InvalidUseOfMatchersException message into your question—that would go a long way in diagnosing your exception. Finally, can you confirm that the `BaseHandler` class is either protected or public, and that `getCookie` is non-final and either protected or public?